# auctex, hooking into wrapping specific environment

Tags: emacs, auctex, hooks

I do a lot of editing using `Emacs` and `auctex`, some of this involve wrapping certain parts of the manus with a certain environment. This is quite easy using `transient-mark-mode` and `C-c C-e`.

But I'd like `Emacs` to do some cleanup on the text as well as wrapping the environment.

As far as I can see `LaTeX-add-environments` is mostly for empty environments, where the interface will ask for information.

Anyone know if it it possible to add a processing hook as well, or do I need to take a different route?

Comment: Reading through http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Adding-Environments.html might give a hint of what is possible?

Comment: @N.N. actually, by looking though `latex.el` I think it have found the answer `LaTeX-after-insert-env-hooks`, `doc.el` use this to add a hook to makesure `macrocode` env is formatted correctly. Sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

To answer my own question

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-after-insert-env-hooks 'LaTeX-after-insert-hint  nil t)
```

where I have defined `LaTeX-after-insert-hint`, just remember that the hook is given `env` (name of environment, should test to see if it is the one the hook should be acting on), `start` (pos just before the inserted `\begin`) and `end` (pos just before inserted `\end`)

EDIT: In the the present case, I'm editing a book, where the author sometimes write hints within the exercises. I'd like those to have a consistent look, so I wrap a `hint` environment around it. The hints often start with `Hint:`, I'd like the environment to provide that, so I want a hook that can clean the contents of the `hint` environment after I have wrapped `hint` around it using `C-c C-e`. This does the trick

```lisp
;; remember start is just before inserted \begin
(defun LaTeX-after-insert-hint (env start end)
  "Do some cleanup of the hint env"
  (when (string-equal env "hint")
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      (forward-line 1)
      ;; only clean if there is a match
      (when (looking-at "[ \t\n]*Hint\: *")
    (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
    )
      (LaTeX-fill-environment 'left)
     )
   )
  )
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-after-insert-env-hooks 'LaTeX-after-insert-hint  nil t)
```

The `(LaTeX-fill-environment 'left)` is not necessary, it is just a nice extra feature.

Comment: I don't understand, what you have done. But as you seem to be a decent user of TeX, Emacs & friends, your answer might be valuable for others. Would you mind to go into some details and publish your code?